# Looping JSON through nested array for to see if all values are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

Basically I want to see how many people purchase the same vendor and how many purchased different brands together. I already know the brands beforehand

I would like to loop through all the objects in this JSON response and if the "vendor" value for all "line_items" are the same then console log "these orders have same brands"+  order number. If they are different console log "these orders have different brands" + order number

```js
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "email": "bob.norman@hostmail.com",
      "order_number": 1001,
      "line_items": [
        {
          "id": 466157049,
          "variant_title": "green",
          "vendor": "Windows"
        },
        {
            "id": 466157049,
            "variant_title": "green",
            "vendor": "Windows"
          }

      ]
    },
    {
        "email": "john.candy@hostmail.com",
        "order_number": 1002,
        "line_items": [
          {
            "id": 466157049,
            "variant_title": "green",
            "vendor": "Windows"
          },
          {
              "id": 466157049,
              "variant_title": "green",
              "vendor": "Apple"
            },
            {
              "id": 466157049,
              "variant_title": "green",
              "vendor": "Windows"
            }
  
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a function that checks if all elements of an array are equal:

```js
const allEqual = ([x, ...ys]) =>
  ys.every(y => y === x);

console.log(
  allEqual([1, 2, 2]),  // false
  allEqual([1, 1, 1]),  // true
  allEqual([1]),        // true
  allEqual([])          // true
);
```

With this out of the way, we can check if a list of item is from a single vendor like so:

```
const itemsAreSameVendor = items =>
  allEqual(items.map(({ vendor }) => vendor));
```

To check if an *order* is a "single vendor order", we write:

```
const orderIsSingleVendor = ({ line_items }) => 
  itemsAreSameVendor(line_items);
```

Now, finding the single orders is a matter of:

```
const singleCount = orderData.orders.filter(orderIsSingleVendor).length;
const multiCount = orderData.orders.length - singleCount;
```

Or, you can use reduce to make two handy groups:

```js
const allEqual = ([x, ...ys]) => 
  ys.every(y => y === x);
  
const itemsAreSameVendor = items =>
  allEqual(items.map(({ vendor }) => vendor));

const orderIsSingleVendor = ({ line_items }) => itemsAreSameVendor(line_items);

console.log(
  orderData().orders.reduce(
    ({ singleVendorOrders, multiVendorOrders }, order) => {
      // Check if this order contains multiple vendors
      const orderType = orderIsSingleVendor(order)
        ? singleVendorOrders
        : multiVendorOrders;

      // Push to the right list
      orderType.push(order.order_number);
      
      return { singleVendorOrders, multiVendorOrders };
    },
    // Format of the result
    { singleVendorOrders: [], multiVendorOrders: [] }
  )
)

function orderData() {
  return {
    "orders": [{
        "email": "bob.norman@hostmail.com",
        "order_number": 1001,
        "line_items": [{
            "id": 466157049,
            "variant_title": "green",
            "vendor": "Windows"
          },
          {
            "id": 466157049,
            "variant_title": "green",
            "vendor": "Windows"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "email": "john.candy@hostmail.com",
        "order_number": 1002,
        "line_items": [{
            "id": 466157049,
            "variant_title": "green",
            "vendor": "Windows"
          },
          {
            "id": 466157049,
            "variant_title": "green",
            "vendor": "Apple"
          },
          {
            "id": 466157049,
            "variant_title": "green",
            "vendor": "Windows"
          }

        ]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

<sub>P.S.: You haven't really shown what exact part you need help with... If you add your own attempt to the question, you'll get better answers and people will be able to point to existing answers solving similar problems.</sub>

Comment: beautiful demonstration of breaking the problem down into small (and reusable!) parts xo

Answer (score 0):

**Loading the JSON into your code**

First you have to load the JSON. If you want to load it from a local archive you'd have to load it creating a function for this. Since loading archives is an asynchronous action, you need to pass a callback to tell the function what to do with that data after it finishes loading. In that callback you'll tell your program what to do with the JSON.

[Here's](https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript) a function implementation to do this. You could also make it for general use and give it a param to especify the file location that then replaces the 'my_data.json' part.

If you want to get the JSON using a GET call to an API or your own backend using Node.js (since the tags of the question say node.js) you can use Node.js's [HTTPS module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) .

With this module you'll want to use especifically [this part](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_url_options_callback) which is a GET passing either options or an URL with a callback.

**Handling the JSON**

Once you have your JSON ready and stored in a variable you'll need to parse it first since it'll come as an string.

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(myJson); //Where myJson is a variable where it is stored
```

Then you'll have your Javascript object with nested array of objects ready to go.

Now onto the loop:

```
parsedJSON.orders.forEach((order) => {
  let areEqual = order['line_items'].reduce((result, item, currentIndex, items) => {
    if (currentIndex === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (currentIndex - 1 < items.length) {
        const previousVendor = items[currentIndex - 1].vendor; //Previous one
        if (y.vendor !== previousVendor) //We compare them
          return result && false; //Since they are different we use the logic operator && with false so this is enough to say that there is an instance where there are at least two different
    }

    return result && true; // <= If they are equal. We can just return acc aswell
  });

  if (areEqual) console.log(order['order_number']);
});
```

If you want this to work for IE11 and less be aware that you can't use arrow functions like I did. Just change them for regular function expressions. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) more info about the reduce function from Javascript array's